# Breaking equation - Problem with brackets

Tags: equations

I want to break a long equation in LaTex. I have tried multline and align but I always get errors with the brackets.

```
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dr_{ij}}{dt} = \frac{1}{2r_{ij}} \left[ 2 \left( x_{i}-x_{j} \right) \left( \dfrac{dx_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dx_{j}}{dt} \right) + 2 \left( y_{i}-y_{j} \right) \left( \dfrac{dy_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dy_{j}}{dt} \right) + 2 \left( z_{i}-z_{j} \right) \left( \dfrac{dz_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dz_{j}}{dt} \right) \right] 
\end{equation}
```

I want to break it in a way, so that all the three "2"s are below each other. How can I do that without getting an error with the brackets?

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{dr_{ij}}{dt} =
\frac{1}{2r_{ij}} \biggl[
  & 2 \left( x_{i}-x_{j} \right) \left( \dfrac{dx_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dx_{j}}{dt} \right) + {}\\
  & 2 \left( y_{i}-y_{j} \right) \left( \dfrac{dy_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dy_{j}}{dt} \right) + {}\\
  & 2 \left( z_{i}-z_{j} \right) \left( \dfrac{dz_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dz_{j}}{dt} \right)
  \biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that we have to manually specify the size for the outermost braces, because `\left` and `\right` cannot be divided across lines.

Comment: you should probably also mention that you've specified the size of the outermost brackets manually instead of using `\left ... \right`, since those can't be separated across lines.

Comment: Is there any way to use `\left ... \right` or any way that adapts the brackets' size automatically?

Comment: @user50224 Sorry, no.

Comment: @egreg: Ok, but in your answer: Why are the brackets before "dx" and especially after "dxj" not aligned perfectly below each other?

Comment: @egreg: How do you set the size of the brackets if you have an equation with compound fractions or even something bigger than that and want to break the formula??

Comment: @user50224 I try to avoid compound fractions in the first place. `\left[<formula>\right.` and `\left.<formula>\right]` with some `\vphantom` may help.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to split large brackets across lines of an equation, it's easiest to set their size manually.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dr_{ij}}{dt} = \frac{1}{2r_{ij}} \biggl[ 
         &2 ( x_{i}-x_{j}) \left( \dfrac{dx_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dx_{j}}{dt} \right) \nonumber \\
   {}+{} &2 ( y_{i}-y_{j}) \left( \dfrac{dy_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dy_{j}}{dt} \right) \nonumber \\
   {}+{} &2 ( z_{i}-z_{j}) \left( \dfrac{dz_{i}}{dt} - \dfrac{dz_{j}}{dt} \right) \biggr]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```